# Messages on product view are not showing. For example: please specify product option(s)

Tags: session, messages

If I want to add a configurable product to cart - without specifying the product options - it used to show up a message like "please specify product option(s)". But this doesn't happen on my site.

I checked, my view.phtml contains

```
<div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?></div>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction what could cause the issue? Could it be disabled somewhere? I didn't find any "remove" tag in my layout.xml.

Thank you so much!

Comment: If you switch back to the default theme, does it function correctly?

Comment: Thanks for your help! Good idea! I tried...but no, the message still do not show up.

Comment: Next step would be to disable your modules, and try again. I would say something could be messing with the Add to Cart controller. Either the message isn't added, or it isn't displayed